# How to use SupportMapFragment instead of MapFragment

Tags: android, namespaces, xamarin, supportmapfragment, mapfragment

I am using Xamarin and am learning the SimpleMapDemo sample code for creating a Google Maps application.

The following variable is declared:

`private MapFragment _mapFragment;`

How can I change this variable to be `SupportMapFragment` instead of `MapFragment`?

I am getting this error:

> Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'SupportMapFragment' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of declaring

```
private MapFragment _mapFragment;
```

do

```
private SupportMapFragment _mapFragment;
```

Also make sure that

1. you have imported android.support.v4.app.Fragment
2. you have android.support.v4.jar in your libs folder and in the project build path

Copy android.support.v4.jar into a lib/ folder inside of your project.

Now select the jar file in that folder, right click -> Build Path -> Add To Build Path.

Comment: Were do I place the android-support-v4.jar file? Currently I have the file in the C:\Users\<usernamr>\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\extras\android\support\v4 folder.

Comment: in to your project `libs` folder

Comment: Is this the path to the libs folder: <Project name>\obj\Debug\__library_projects__?

Comment: The path is <ProjectName>/libs

Comment: I am using Xamarin, and I do not have a libs folder. Should I just create one?